# PHP Prepared Statement - Echoing the values

Tags: php, mysql

I recently fixed my old and incredibly insecure MySQL query with prepared statements. However, when I run this new query, I'm not being returned any values except when I use print_r for debugging. If I simply echo the value (i.e echo $eventid), I'll get an error that I can't convert an array to string. Do I need to add some sort of foreach loop to this query? Thank you all so much for continuing to help me learn! :)

```
   <?php
echo "<div class='container target'>

        <div class='container'>    
    <div id='quick-access'>
      <form class='form-inline quick-search-form' role='form'>
        <div class='form-group'>
                <input type='text' id='name' name='name' class='form-control' placeholder='Driver name'>
        </div>
        <button type='submit' id='quick-search' class='btn btn-custom'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search custom-glyph-color'></span></button>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>";
?>


<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'Username', 'password', 'Database');

if($conn->connect_errno > 0)
{
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}

# SQL WITH QMARK PLACEHOLDER (USING TABLE ALIASES)
$sql = "SELECT e.personaId, e.ID AS event_id, e.EVENTID, e.rank, e.carId, 
               e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds, 
               p.iconIndex, p.cash, p.level, p.created, p.score, p.motto, 
               p.repAtCurrentLevel, p.rep, p.name AS p_name
        FROM EVENT_DATA e
        INNER JOIN PERSONA p ON e.personaId = p.ID
        WHERE (p.name = ? AND e.EVENTID = '43' 
          AND  e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds > '0')";

# INITIALIZE ARRAYS - TWO METHODS: array() or []
$name = array(); $avatarimg = []; $cash = array(); $level = array(); $createddate = [];
$driverscore = array(); $motto = []; $repcurrent = array(); $reptotal = []; 
$personaid = array(); $eventid = []; $milliseconds = array();

# PREPARED STATEMENT
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

# BIND PARAM 
$param=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['name']);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param);


# EXECUTE STATEMENT
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    # CHECK ROWS 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  { 
       # ITERATE THROUGH ROWS
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            # APPEND TO ARRAYS
            $name[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['p_name']);
            $avatarimg[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['iconIndex']);
            $cash[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['cash']);
            $level[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['level']);
            $createddate[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['created']);
            $driverscore[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['score']);
            $motto[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['motto']);
            $repcurrent[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['repAtCurrentLevel']);
            $reptotal[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['rep']);
            $personaid[] = $row['personaId'];
            $eventid[] = $row['EVENTID'];
            $milliseconds[] = $row['alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds'];    
       }    
    }    
}



 print_r($name);
  print_r($eventid);


?>
```

Comment: "If I simply echo the value (i.e echo $eventid), I'll get an error that I can't convert an array to string" -> well, `$eventid` is an array since you're using `$eventid[] = $row['EVENTID']` on it for every resulting row. Why are you expecting otherwise?

Comment: You don't need to do real_escape_string, if you are using prepared statement

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Well, especially when *retrieving* stuff from the database. This is meant to be used upon storing data (but yes, not needed when using prepared statements anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$name[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['p_name']);` it adding every single result of your select query into an array. That is why when you try to echo it is not working.

Here is an easy way to see it.

```
foreach ($name as $n) {
    echo $n . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: So how would I go about formatting this array with a foreach loop?

Comment: Yeah, but I still need to output all values of $name (in this case is 5 usernames.) only echoing $name without the array would give me one output, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: That's the event ID for the user. In this case, this member has 5 times on that event.

Comment: Aight! I updated the solution with a foreach example, let me know if it works.

Comment: Didn't I already vote for it though? I clicked the green checkmark.